# Chrome Extension: Tab ID returns negative 1 for PDF files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf

I have this extension which copies the selected (plain) text along with the link of the website. Now, it works fine except when you run it on a pdf file opened in a tab.

Basically it creates a context menu with the background script which send a message to the content script whenever it is clicked which in turn runs this simple line of code:

`navigator.clipboard.writeText(request.websitelink[1] + "\n\n" + request.websitelink[0]);`

*Now to send the message to the content script also requires to send the tab id where the problem occurs.*

**If I open up the inspector for the service worker after I click the context menu, it returns this error:**

`Error in event handler: TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.sendMessage(integer tabId, any message, optional object options, optional function responseCallback): Error at parameter 'tabId': Value must be at least 0.`

Any solutions?

**manifest.json** :

```
{
  "name": "Select text with page link",
  "description": "This extension allows you to copy text from any website with the link.",
  "version": "2.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "clipboardRead"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*","file:///*","*://*/*.pdf"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**background.js** :

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Copy text with current website link.", 
  contexts:["selection"], 
  id: "copyLinkText"
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(
(info,tab) => {
    if(tab.id == -1) {
    console.log("It is a pdf.");
    }
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {websitelink: [info.pageUrl,info.selectionText]},function(response) {
      console.log(info.pageUrl);
      console.log(info.selectionText);
  })
});
```

**content.js** :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(request.websitelink[1] + "\n\n" + request.websitelink[0]);
    sendResponse({respondance: "Im good mate."});
    return true;
});
```

Sorry if my code is bad...

Comment: did you fix this?. If yes plz share the solution.

Comment: Never did. However I did find out that it returns -1 because the pdf file displayed by chrome is from one of chrome's inbuilt extensions. Extensions cannot access tabs from other extensions.

Comment: Hence it is not a normal tab.

Comment: yeah @cherryguy thanks, it's not possible